# Can't debug servlet Eclipse + Glassfish

Tags: java, debugging, servlets

The server is in debugging mode. I've set 10 breakpoints and the browser just skips them all. Why? This happens with JSPs also in that project. Why?

Comment: How do you mean browser just skips them? Which version of eclipse and which version of java do you use? May be this should be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370868/eclipse-debugger-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoint

Comment: Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415 and jdk 1.6.0_20 and JRE 1.6

Comment: Now it says Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Is there something about port 8000 that I should know/do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the Debbuger is indeed connected with Glassfish? Also please note that it is not possible for the debugger to stop at breakpoints which have been set inside jsp. AFAIK, debugger works only pure java code

Comment: Breakpoints stop at java code inside JSP.It works with Tomcat..It`s something about Glassfish. How do I connect the Debugger to glassfish?

Answer (score 0):

So you are connecting to external server with "debug remote java application".

What is your server's debug port? Port 8000 is default setting in eclipse debug configuration for remote java appilcation. You should change that value to one that GlassFish server is configured for debugging.

Also, take a look at [How do I debug GlassFish 3 using Eclipse Helios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305881/how-do-i-debug-glassfish-3-using-eclipse-helios)