# OEPE glassfish debug connection refused

Tags: eclipse, oracle, debugging, glassfish

I am having the same problem as indicated by this thread. 
[How do I debug GlassFish 3 using Eclipse Helios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305881/how-do-i-debug-glassfish-3-using-eclipse-helios)

I did use the "debug" instead "run" on the glassfish 3.1.1 server. Eclipse is Indigo. OEPE 11.1.1.8. I have a customized domain in which I changed all the port numbers, for server debug port, I used 10009. I am able to start the server, but the debugger is not working and shows "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused." Eclipses log shows:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching 4 113 2011-12-01 10:29:42.602
!MESSAGE Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
!STACK 0
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService$2.run(SocketTransportService.java:136)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am using jdk1.7 (OEPE declares it supports up to 1.6, but I don't a simple socket connection for debugger won't work due to this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that glassfish eclipse plugin does not support customized domain port. The debug port is fixed to be 9009 as of the current version.