# Eclipse debugger breakpoint flakiness w/Glassfish

Tags: eclipse, debugging, glassfish

in Eclipse Indigo with Glassfish 3.1.2 on Linux/Ubuntu.  JDK 1.6.0_32.

**Update** same results on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Eclipse Juno w/latest Eclipse Glassfish plugin.

Eclipse debugger stops on breakpoints, but does not synchronize the 'debug' tab to the current thread/location, and does not show the cursor at the current line.  If I manually expand the tabs for each thread, I can figure out which thread is stopped and what line.  If I click on that I can then show the pointer on the current line.  Once I step over/into (F5/F6), though, the current-line cursor disappears again and I have to do it all over.

Debugger *does* work fine with JUnit and Java SE apps.  Also the very *first* time I launch Eclipse and Glassfish, everything works.  If I restart Glassfish though, the debugger flakes out until I restart Eclipse again.

Any one seen this and had found a fix?

Comment: ive had it in indigo, but not in juno

Comment: When i think about it i cleaned up the projects a lot when moving, also with indigo i had oepe package and with juno just clean eclipse ee. So might not have been the switch that mattered

Comment: I see this flaky behavior too.  It works the first time, but not again until I restart everything.  Java 7u10, Eclipse Juno, Glassfish 3.1.2.2.  It is so frustrating.

Comment: I still have the same problem in Juno even w/Glassfish plugin update to latest.

Comment: I see the same behavior. I am using Windows 7, Glassfish 3.1.2.2, and Indigo Service Release 2. If I could figure out a consistent way to get the debugger to stop and take me to the line it is on, I would be happy. But, for me, simply restarting Eclipse does not do the trick. Seems like once it starts working, it keeps working. wrschneider99, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: wrschneider99, did you ever figure out a solution to this? I am guessing a child process of the glassfish server is not being shut down properly. Perhaps killing it would get things to work. As it stands now, I need to do a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with this error described by **wrschneider99** for 2 days. I thought that I do not find solution. I noticed that when i "open launch configuration" for my glassfish  server then error message "No server selected" is shown. I found defects for this [Defect1](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-343?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel), and [Defect2](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-361?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel). Following suggestions I installed glassfish server plugin by putting in eclipse install new software link

```
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/juno/
```

After that problem with "No server selected" disappear and debugging problem was fixed too!
I used linux x64 and eclipse indigo. It look that in eclipse marketplace glassfish plugin is not up to date.

Comment: No luck for me.  I have installed clean Eclipse Juno and latest Glassfish server plugin for Glassfish 3.1.2.2.  Same problem with debugger.  Works the first time but not after restarting Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old. But, upgrading to Eclipse Kepler and Glassfish 4 seems to have solved the problem for me.